# Loading Hdfy files with pytorch data loader

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow-datasets, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I am new to PyTorch and I used to work with TensorFlow. But for some reason, I have to work with PyTorch now. My training, test, and validation data are in Hdfy format. I intend to load the data (not at once to avoid memory problems) and feed it batch by batch to the network.

This is the script that I used to work with Tensorflow. Can anyone here help me to build the exact one with Pytorch?

```
class Generator(object):
     def __init__(self,open_directory,batch_size,name_x,name_y):

    self.open_directory = open_directory

    data_f = h5py.File(open_directory, "r")

    self.x = data_f[name_x]
    self.y = data_f[name_y]

    if len(self.x.shape) == 4:
        self.shape_x = (None, self.x.shape[1], self.x.shape[2], self.x.shape[3])

    if len(self.x.shape) == 3:
        self.shape_x = (None, self.x.shape[1], self.x.shape[2])

    if len(self.y.shape) == 4:
        self.shape_y = (None, self.y.shape[1], self.y.shape[2], self.y.shape[3])

    if len(self.y.shape) == 3:
        self.shape_y = (None, self.y.shape[1], self.y.shape[2])

    self.num_samples = self.x.shape[0]
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.epoch_size = self.num_samples//self.batch_size+1*(self.num_samples % self.batch_size!= 0)

    self.pointer = 0
    self.sample_nums = np.arange(0, self.num_samples)
    np.random.shuffle(self.sample_nums)


def data_generator(self):

    for batch_num in range(self.epoch_size):

        x = []
        y = []

        for elem_num in range(self.batch_size):

            sample_num = self.sample_nums[self.pointer]

            x += [self.x[sample_num]]
            y += [self.y[sample_num]]

            self.pointer += 1

            if self.pointer == self.num_samples:
                self.pointer = 0
                np.random.shuffle(self.sample_nums)
                break

        x = np.array(x,
                     dtype=np.float32)
        y = np.array(y,
                     dtype=np.float32)

        yield x, y

    def get_dataset(self):
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(self.data_generator,
                                             output_types=(tf.float32,
                                                           tf.float32),
                                             output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape(self.shape_x),
                                                            tf.TensorShape(self.shape_y)))
        dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

    return dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
class TorchGenerator(Dataset):

# Constructor
def __init__(self, open_directory, name_x, name_y):
    self.data_f = h5py.File(open_directory, "r")
    self.x = self.data_f[name_x]
    self.y = self.data_f[name_y]

def __len__(self):
    return self.x.shape[0]

# Getter
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    samplex = self.x[idx]
    sampley = self.y[idx]

    return samplex, sample
```

training_data = TorchGenerator(open_directory + "file.hdf5", 'X_train_arr', 'Y_train_arr')

Then using pytorch Dataloader, you can find more details [in this link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(training_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).